# Filtering <tr> from table based on search criteria. Is this a good approach for a search module?

Tags: jquery, html

I believe this is a nice implementation so I decided to ask here since I did not find any results in google.

I have a table with a number of rows containing results from a database query. It is a search module and I would like to capture every character input and filter off the table the results that does not match the value been input.

What is the best way to proceed? I was thinking of check every `<tr>` id and if the search criteria does not match the string in the id attribute this `<tr>` is hidden.

I  was thinking of use a ajax request to post the input but the network traffic will increase and the search will not be so fast.

Comment: The best way to proceed is to write some code and show us what you have done so that we can help.

Comment: DataTables, a very good jQuery table plugin, does this but it loads all the data and uses javascript to filter what it shows.  Have a look at it here... http://datatables.net/

Comment: Why don't you instead filter your query and re-create the table? I mean, of course, if you can update your query...

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think that filter visual components is a good approach. HTML is just visual data.

I would rather create the data as a collection of objects, then use this collection as source of the table. Whenever you change the source, update the generated output. This will give you more flexibility, but also a separation of concerns.

I use knockoutJS for this matter.

Cheers.